# Move files from folders/subfolders to same folder structure in another folder

Tags: excel, vba, file, move

I have Excel VBA code that move files from one folder to another based on a list in Excel. However, I have to go subfolder by subfolder to get the files.

I want to modify the script such that it searches for the files from the main folder (that contains subfolders) and moves the respective files to the respective sub folder contained in another main folder with the same folder structure as the original main folder.

Original folder structure:

```
Main Folder1
|
|______fold1
| |_____file1.wav
| |_____file2.wav
|
|______fold2
| |_____file1.wav
| |_____file2.wav
|
|______fold3
|_____file1.wav
|_____file2.wav
```

The move to folder structure:

```
Moved2Folder
|
|______fold1
|
|______fold2
|
|______fold3
```

Here is the move to script that I use on individual folders:

```vb
    Dim xVal As String
    On Error Resume Next
    Set xRg = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", "BoBO Man", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    If xRg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Set xSFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xSFileDlg.Title = " Please select the original folder:"
    If xSFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xSPathStr = xSFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    Set xDFileDlg = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    xDFileDlg.Title = " Please select the destination folder:"
    If xDFileDlg.Show <> -1 Then Exit Sub
    xDPathStr = xDFileDlg.SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    For Each xCell In xRg
        xVal = xCell.Value
        If TypeName(xVal) = "String" And xVal <> "" Then
            FileCopy xSPathStr & xVal, xDPathStr & xVal
            Kill xSPathStr & xVal
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

How to move the found files from the Main Folder1 subfolders to the respective Moved2Folder subfolders?

I posted this question on the [Mr. Excel website](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/move-files-from-list-found-in-folders-subfolders-to-same-folder-structure-in-another-folder.1204131/).

Comment: Do all of the folders from the source folder already exist in the destination folder?

Comment: @TimWilliams, Yes, all the subfolders in the `Move2Folder`already exist.  Thanks!

Comment: What is contained in `xRg`?  Just the file names themselves, with no path information?

Comment: @TimWilliams, just the file names themselves.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```vb
Sub CopySelected()
    
    Dim rngFileNames As Range, srcPath As String, destPath As String
    Dim colFiles As Collection, f
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngFileNames = Application.InputBox("Please select the file names:", _
                   "BoBO Man", ActiveWindow.RangeSelection.Address, , , , , 8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rngFileNames Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    srcPath = GetFolderPath("Please select the original folder:")
    If Len(srcPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    destPath = GetFolderPath("Please select the destination folder:")
    If Len(destPath) = 0 Then Exit Sub
    
    Set colFiles = GetMatches(srcPath, "*") 'get all source folder files
    For Each f In colFiles                  'loop source folder files
        'does the file name match one of the selected names?
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(f.Name, rngFileNames, 0)) Then
            f.Copy Replace(f.Path, srcPath, destPath) 'copy this file
        End If
    Next f
    
End Sub

'get a folder from the user - returns empty string if no selection
Function GetFolderPath(msg As String) As String
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .Title = msg
        If .Show = -1 Then GetFolderPath = .SelectedItems.Item(1) & "\"
    End With
End Function

'Return a collection of file objects given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.txt"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection

    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fpath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        
        Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        
        fpath = fldr.Path
        If Right(fpath, 1) <> "\" Then fpath = fpath & "\"
        f = Dir(fpath & filePattern) 'Dir is faster...
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            colFiles.Add fso.GetFile(fpath & f)
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Comment: Your code works perfectly!  Sincerest THANK YOU!