# Mass Find & Replace including subfolders

Tags: vba, ms-word, batch-processing, docx

I don't really know VBA but have had some success with manipulating code in the past. I'm getting stuck with this one, where I tried to mix 2 different ideas into one. What I want to do is a mass find & replace with pop-up boxes to (1) select or insert the path (that includes subfolders); (2) insert the "find text"; (3) insert the "replace text"; and (4) cycle through all .docx files in all subfolders.

I found this code to do what I want on a single folder, but can't figure out how to manipulate it to include subfolders:

```
Sub FindAndReplaceInFolder()
  Dim objDoc As Document
  Dim strFile As String
  Dim strFolder As String
  Dim strFindText As String
  Dim strReplaceText As String
 
  '  Pop up input boxes for user to enter folder path, the finding and replacing texts.
  strFolder = InputBox("Enter folder path here:")
  strFile = Dir(strFolder & "\" & "*.docx", vbNormal)
  strFindText = InputBox("Enter finding text here:")
  strReplaceText = InputBox("Enter replacing text here:")
 
  '  Open each file in the folder to search and replace texts. Save and close the file after the action.
  While strFile <> ""
    Set objDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strFolder & "\" & strFile)
    With objDoc
      With Selection
        .HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
        With Selection.Find
          .text = strFindText
          .Replacement.text = strReplaceText
          .Forward = True
          .Wrap = wdFindContinue
          .Format = False
          .MatchCase = False
          .MatchWholeWord = False
          .MatchWildcards = False
          .MatchSoundsLike = False
          .MatchAllWordForms = False
        End With
        Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
      End With
      objDoc.Save
      objDoc.Close
      strFile = Dir()
    End With
  Wend
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/72178926/478884 for a function which will return a Collection of file objects given a start folder and a filename pattern: it will also search subfolders.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that addresses my issue. The code I provided works and does what I want, EXCEPT I want it to also include docs in subfolders. Basically I want to find and replace all docs in all folders instead of one folder at at time. There are 54 folders and probably 400 or so documents. There are several F&R terms to cycle through that I would only have to do once if the code could be tweaked to include folders/subfolders. As it is, I have to search each term for each of the 54 folders, which is a lot of extra work.

Comment: In subfolders of one parent folder, or in subfolders of many different parent folders?

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/47347-post12.html.html for processing a single folder, and the mods in https://www.msofficeforums.com/47785-post14.html for processing sub-folders as well. The finished code is in https://www.msofficeforums.com/47846-post15.html.

Comment: @macropod I saw that one before posting. It doesn't work for me. I need pop-up windows as described in my original post. I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to make changes.

Comment: @TimWilliams Subfolders of a single parent folder.

Comment: Then the function I linked to should give you a good start: pass it a parent folder and a file pattern like "*.docx" and it will give you a Collection of all matching files under the starting folder.  You can then loop over that collection and process each file in turn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

«I need pop-up windows as described in my original post. I'm not familiar enough with this stuff to make changes» For example:

```
Option Explicit
Dim FSO As Object, oFolder As Object, StrFolds As String, StrFnd As String, StrRep As String
 
Sub Main()
Dim TopLevelFolder As String, TheFolders As Variant, aFolder As Variant, i As Long
StrFnd = InputBox("Enter finding text here:")
If StrFnd = "" Then Exit Sub
StrRep = InputBox("Enter replacing text here:")
TopLevelFolder = GetFolder
If TopLevelFolder = "" Then Exit Sub
StrFolds = vbCr & TopLevelFolder
If FSO Is Nothing Then
  Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
End If
'Get the sub-folder structure
Set TheFolders = FSO.GetFolder(TopLevelFolder).SubFolders
For Each aFolder In TheFolders
  RecurseWriteFolderName (aFolder)
Next
'Process the documents in each folder
For i = 1 To UBound(Split(StrFolds, vbCr))
  Call UpdateDocuments(CStr(Split(StrFolds, vbCr)(i)))
Next
End Sub
 
 
Sub RecurseWriteFolderName(aFolder)
Dim SubFolders As Variant, SubFolder As Variant
Set SubFolders = FSO.GetFolder(aFolder).SubFolders
StrFolds = StrFolds & vbCr & CStr(aFolder)
On Error Resume Next
For Each SubFolder In SubFolders
  RecurseWriteFolderName (SubFolder)
Next
End Sub


Sub UpdateDocuments(oFolder As String)
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim strInFolder As String, strFile As String, wdDoc As Document
strInFolder = oFolder
strFile = Dir(strInFolder & "\*.doc", vbNormal)
While strFile <> ""
  Set wdDoc = Documents.Open(FileName:=strInFolder & "\" & strFile, AddToRecentFiles:=False, Visible:=False)
  With wdDoc
    With .Range.Find
      .ClearFormatting
      .Replacement.ClearFormatting
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindContinue
      .Format = False
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = False
      .MatchWildcards = False
      .MatchSoundsLike = False
      .MatchAllWordForms = False
      .Text = StrFnd
      .Replacement.Text = StrRep
      .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    'Save and close the document
    .Close SaveChanges:=True
  End With
  strFile = Dir()
Wend
Set wdDoc = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
 
Function GetFolder() As String
Dim oFolder As Object
GetFolder = ""
Set oFolder = CreateObject("Shell.Application").BrowseForFolder(0, "Choose a folder", 0)
If (Not oFolder Is Nothing) Then GetFolder = oFolder.Items.Item.Path
Set oFolder = Nothing
End Function
```

As coded, the macro will process .doc, .docx, and .docm files. To limit it to .docx files, change the .doc reference to .docx.

Comment: Thank you! That is working, but it is creating a new subfolder inside every existing folder called "Output". Nothing is in the new subfolder. Can it work without creating that folder at all? Also, in some of my templates, I have text inside of a text box that is part of the document header. Is there a way for it to do the find & replace inside that, too? Asking too much?? lol!

Comment: Try the revised code.

Comment: It starts to work, and after some processing time, I get this error: Run-time error '4198': Command failed.  The option to Debug is greyed out so I don't know what the issue is, but I think maybe it could be the length of the path and/or file name at the point the error generates? Can you add a "skip & keep processing" command? I truly appreciate all of your help with this. It's already a big time-saver!

Comment: Update. I moved my folder so it wasn't buried in a long document path and that resolved the issue. I'll mark this as the solution. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I mean something like this:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FindAndReplaceInFolder()
    Dim colFiles As Collection, f
    Dim strFolder As String, strFindText As String, strReplaceText As String
    
    'Pop up input boxes for user to enter folder path, the finding and replacing texts.
    '(fixed values for testing...)
    strFolder = "C:\Temp\SO\"        'InputBox("Enter folder path here:")
    strFindText = "several"          'InputBox("Enter finding text here:")
    strReplaceText = "three or four" 'InputBox("Enter replacing text here:")
    
    Set colFiles = GetMatches(strFolder, "*.docx")
    For Each f In colFiles
        Debug.Print "Processing: " & f
        ReplaceInFile CStr(f), strFindText, strReplaceText
    Next f
    Debug.Print "Processed " & colFiles.Count & " files"
End Sub

'replace all instances of `strFindText` with `strReplaceText` in file at `fPath`
Sub ReplaceInFile(fPath As String, strFindText As String, strReplaceText As String)
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = Documents.Open(fPath)
    With doc.Content.Find
        .Text = strFindText
        .Replacement.Text = strReplaceText
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    doc.Close savechanges:=True
End Sub

'Return a collection of file paths given a starting folder and a file pattern
'  e.g. "*.docx"
'Pass False for last parameter if don't want to check subfolders
Function GetMatches(startFolder As String, filePattern As String, _
                    Optional subFolders As Boolean = True) As Collection
    Dim fso, fldr, f, subFldr, fPath
    Dim colFiles As New Collection
    Dim colSub As New Collection
    
    Set fso = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    colSub.Add startFolder
    
    Do While colSub.Count > 0
        Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))
        colSub.Remove 1
        If subFolders Then
            For Each subFldr In fldr.subFolders
                colSub.Add subFldr.Path
            Next subFldr
        End If
        fPath = fldr.Path
        If Right(fPath, 1) <> "\" Then fPath = fPath & "\"
        f = Dir(fPath & filePattern) 'Dir is faster...
        Do While Len(f) > 0
            colFiles.Add fPath & f
            f = Dir()
        Loop
    Loop
    Set GetMatches = colFiles
End Function
```

Output:

```txt
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\tester - Copy (2).docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\tester - Copy - Copy.docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\tester - Copy.docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\tester.docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\blah\tester - Copy (2).docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\blah\tester - Copy - Copy.docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\blah\tester - Copy.docx
Processing: C:\Temp\SO\blah\tester.docx
Processed 8 files
```

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I'm getting this error: "Run-time Error ‘76’: Path not found" at this line: Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1))

Comment: If the path provided is valid then that should be fine.  Did you remove my fixed testing values in `FindAndReplaceInFolder` and uncomment the `InputBox()` calls?

Comment: That was the problem. It works now. Thank you!

Comment: Spoke too soon. I'm getting a new error -- "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" at this line: Set fldr = fso.getfolder(colSub(1)). Same line as before, but new error.

Comment: Are you using `GetMatches` exactly as posted?

Comment: Yes. I didn't make any changes, except as instructed above.

Comment: Still working fine for me if I copy that entire code into a new Word document.