# Search and replace wildcard in word documents

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created this macro script that suppose to do the following:

1. Ask the user to select a directory.
2. Search for all docx files in the selected directory.

For each file found:

1. Open the file.
2. Replace a wildcard with an empty string.
3. Save the file

For some reason, text is not being replaced and the file is not saved.

```
Sub Remove_time_blocks()
Dim WdDoc As Document, sFile As String
Dim FilePath As String

Dim dlgSaveAs As FileDialog
Set dlgSaveAs = Application.FileDialog( _
FileDialogType:=msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

If dlgSaveAs.Show = -1 Then
    FilePath = dlgSaveAs.SelectedItems(1)
   
    sFile = Dir(FilePath & "/*.docx")
    'Loop through all .doc files in that path
    Do While sFile <> ""
        Set WdDoc = Application.Documents.Open(FilePath & "\" & sFile)

        With WdDoc.Content.Find
             .Forward = True
             .Wrap = wdFindStop
             .Text = "^l^l[0-9]{1,}^l*:*--*,[0-9]{3}"
             .Replacement.Text = ""
             .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll, Forward:=True
        End With

        WdDoc.Save
        sFile = Dir
    Loop
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: You haven’t told `Find` that you want to use wildcards, so it is searching for a literal string. If you don’t know what parameters to use, record a macro.

Comment: See, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222147/mass-find-replace-including-subfolders/72253236#72253236. The code I posted there processes sub-folders as well.